# 127.x.y.z but not 127.0.0.0?

Tags: localhost, loopback

I was looking around on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4822965), when I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4822965/#comment5349737_4823013).

> My home is 127.1.2.3, ha! In fact everything that starts with "127." resolves to the local host. – [TToni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20703/ttoni) [Jan 27 '11 at 23:30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822965/what-does-localhost8080-mean#comment5349737_4823013)

I tried this by going to http://127.1.2.3 and http://127.174.199.127 and other random URLs that all lead to http://localhost

Except for one of them: http://127.0.0.0

After waiting some time I get

> ### This site can’t be reached
>
> **127.0.0.0** took too long to respond.

Error Code: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

What is special about http://127.0.0.0 that it can't be reached?

---

Another thing: something similar occurs with http://127.255.255.255

> ### This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at **http://127.255.255.255/** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Error Code: `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`

Note: this happens immediately, meaning no waiting for about 10-15 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with a lot of things IP related, `127.0.0.0` is the "network" address, so no host should claim it.

The subnet is defined as `127.0.0.0/8` or `127.0.0.0` with a netmask of `255.0.0.0` which means the network address is `127.0.0.0` and the broadcast address is `127.255.255.255`, both of which are reserved.

For any given subnet, the first address is considered the network, the last the broadcast. The remainder is the host addresses.

For smaller subnets, like `/24` (`255.255.255.0`) the range is proportionately smaller, and for some like a `/29` smaller still. Any smaller is just silly as you end up with nothing more than a network and broadcast address, it's not a usable subnet.

Note: `/32` isn't a subnet, it's only used as a way of saying "host address" for things like firewall rules.

Many IP stacks respond to *any* valid `127.0.0.0/8` address, not just `127.0.0.1`, but they will not respond to the network address.

In other words, the valid IP range is `127.0.0.1` through `127.255.255.254` for host addresses.

Comment: OK thank you for your response.  So 127.0.0.0 isn't available because it is the network address and 127.255.255.255 is the broadcast address?  And all other 127.x.y.z addresses are available?

Comment: On any normal IP stack, like in a mainstream operating system, yes. Caveat: This is not guaranteed on all implementations, like some embedded platforms and old stacks may behave differently. I cannot guarantee that your IoT toaster behaves this way.